# Compare SQL table to itself to find missing timesheet dates

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

The SQL query below works but it takes forever to respond because of the sub-queries being used. I'm hoping someone can spot a way for me to optimize this query.

```
SELECT     a.Userid, a.Date, a.[Total Hrs], a.[Load Date],
                  c.[First Name], c.[Last Name] 
FROM         dbo.TimeSheetReport AS a 
                  INNER JOIN
                  Candidates AS c ON a.Userid = c.Userid 
AND a.Date >= c.[Confirmed Start Date] 
AND (a.Date <= c.[Planned End Date] or c.[Planned End Date] is null)
WHERE a.[Load Date] = @ddlendDate 
AND a.Date not in 
(select b.Date from dbo.TimeSheetReport AS b 
where b.[Load Date] = @ddlstartDate and a.Userid = b.Userid)
AND a.Date < (select MAX(date) from dbo.TimeSheetReport AS c 
where c.[Load Date] = @ddlstartDate)
```

Each subset of data is created based on when the data was loaded (i.e. Load Date). It looks for any days from the current load (@ddlendDate) that were missing from a previous load (@ddlstartDate).

I tried using a LEFT OUTER JOIN on itself, but I get zero records returned and I know they exist.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting the NOT IN to NOT EXISTS reduced the query execution time from 12+ minutes to under 10 seconds.

```
SELECT     a.Userid, a.Date, a.[Total Hrs], a.[Load Date],
                  c.[First Name], c.[Last Name] 
FROM         dbo.TimeSheetReport AS a 
                  INNER JOIN
                  Candidates AS c ON a.Userid = c.Userid 
AND a.Date >= c.[Confirmed Start Date] 
AND (a.Date <= c.[Planned End Date] or c.[Planned End Date] is null)
WHERE a.[Load Date] = @ddlendDate 
AND NOT EXISTS (select 1 from dbo.TimeSheetReport AS b 
WHERE b.[Load Date] = @ddlstartDate AND a.Userid = b.Userid AND a.Date = b.Date)
AND a.Date < (select MAX(date) from dbo.TimeSheetReport AS c 
WHERE c.[Load Date] = @ddlstartDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use e **Common Table Expression** (see this link for more information: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx) or a temp table for the first sub-query.

The second one can be stored in a variable and does not need to be defined as a subquery (so it will be executed only once)

```
declare @MaDate DateTime 
select @MaDate = MAX([date])  from dbo.TimeSheetReport AS c  where c.[Load Date] = @ddlstartDate

SELECT     a.Userid, a.Date, a.[Total Hrs], a.[Load Date],
                  c.[First Name], c.[Last Name] 
FROM         dbo.TimeSheetReport AS a 
 INNER JOIN   Candidates AS c ON a.Userid = c.Userid 
        AND a.Date >= c.[Confirmed Start Date] 
        AND (a.Date <= c.[Planned End Date] or c.[Planned End Date] is null)
WHERE a.[Load Date] = @ddlendDate 
    AND a.Date not in 
        (select b.Date from dbo.TimeSheetReport AS b 
         where b.[Load Date] = @ddlstartDate and a.Userid = b.Userid)
    AND a.Date < @MaDate
```

Comment: Thanks for the partial solution. Your first suggestion doesn't work and this sub-query is the most taxing that needs to be solved. The second one looks helpful.